# Java delimiter for * and / in string tokens

Tags: java, regex, string

I have  a string like 22 + 4 * 3 / 4

Now, I need to extract the tokens from this string. Here is my one line code:

```
String[] tokens  = str.split( [ +-*/]+ )
```

basically my delimiter string is [+-*/] As I want to split on the symbols + - * /

but then, unfortunately, this conflicts with regex version of *, /
I tried adding backslash to * and /  as [+-\*\/] but it doesnt help.

How do I make Java compile *, / by their literal meaning? I thought I had done as per the java documentation on patterns http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#sum

what did I miss here?

thanks

Comment: Put the `-` at the beginning or end.

Comment: didn't help : (  how would that solve the issue btw?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, when used in a character class, `*` and `+` lose their special meaning (after all they would make no sense in a character class). Therefore, we don't need to escape these characters. Conversely, `-` *only* has a special meaning in a character class, but only if it used between characters, where it indicates a range. If it is used at the start or end, it has no special meaning. So, we have:

```
[ +*/-]+
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/Tax0CbvtsmEiChyV)

Comment: Thank you all !! thanks @arshajii for concise explanation!

Answer (score 2):

In [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) `[...]` `-` is special character used to create range of characters like `a-z`. To make it literal you need to place it at start of class character `[-...]`, end of class character `[...-]` or just simply escape it with `\` which in Java needs to be written as `"\\-"`. Try this way

```
String[] tokens  = str.split("[ +\\-*/]+");
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to parse your string?  My guess would be you are trying to perform lexical analysis (scanning) of an input stream.

- You could hand-roll a scanner by building strtok, and character lookahead/pushback.
- You could use a took like lex, or flex to build a lexical scanner
- You could a series of regular expressions and case statements for a poor mans parser

Suppose you do want to tokenize your algebraic string.  You need to define a grammar and what tokens you want to recognize.  You need something like BNF (Backus-Naur Formalism), or you could use 'railroad syntax diagrams' (personally, I prefer BNF, but some people like railroad diagrams).

Here is a start:

```
expression --> sexpr | nil
parenexpr  --> '(' sexpr ')'
sexpr   --> parenexpr | addexpr | thing | nil
addexpr --> mulexpr addop mulexpr | mulexpr
mulexpr --> parenexpr
thing   --> symbol | integer | real | scientific
integer --> { '+' | '-' }? digit+
real    --> { '+' | '-' }? digit+ { . digit+ }?
scientific --> { + | - }? digit+ { . digit+ } e { '+' | '-' }? digit+
addop   --> '+' | '-'
mulop   --> '/' | '*' | '^' | '%'
relop   --> '||' | '&&' | '!'
symbol  --> { character | '_' } { character | '_' | digit }*
digit   --> [0-9]
character --> [A-Za-z]
//etc
```

What this means, is that each item to the left of the grammar production symbol (-->) expands to one of the things on the right.  Note that this definition is recursive, which gives you an idea of the sort of programming you will need.  Anyway, you will want to scan and identify each token to collect integer, real, scientific, symbol, addop, mulop, relop, and any other tokens you want to extract.  Along the way, you need to decide how to handle whitespace (tab, space, newline), and other undefined symbols.